# MP3 Player not recognized on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, mount

Whenever I connect my MP3 Player it just starts charging, and is not registered by the computer. Already tried with several usb connections and ports to no avail. I am using a laptop with an intel gpu,cpu, and Ubuntu 20.04. Any help would be appreciated; I need to access the MP3's contents.

Comment: Is there a settings in the mp3 player which allows it to be recognized as a mass storage? Something similar is there for Android devices. If not enabled, they just charge.

Comment: Nope, I've already looked. Besides, I've been able to use it before on a windows computer, so that's why I think it has more to do with Linux.

Comment: No, not really, What makes the device detect a data link as opposed to charging only is the USB port and whatever is in-between, not the OS. You may want to try a different **cable**.

Comment: Okay. I've tried a few different ones, but no results. Maybe I'll see if I can find a usb-c to microUSB connection and try that.